# Django Rest: On axios post for user_id key, null is always returned, even with a value for user_id sent

Tags: javascript, post, django-rest-framework, axios

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVdu1.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eik6f.png)

I send over the value for user_id, it receives it and then returns it always as null. It is posting to a foreignkey, just not entirely sure what i am missing here.

Post

```
 const article = {
        "deck_name": deck_name.value,
        "deck_type": deck_type.value,
        "user_id": user_id,
    }
    var CSRF_TOKEN = "{{csrf_token}}"
    console.log(user_id.value)
    headers = {
        headers: {
        'X-CSRFToken': CSRF_TOKEN,
        }
    }
      response = axios.post('http://localhost:8000/rest/decks/', article, headers)
      console.log(response.status_code, response.content)
```

Seriliazer

```
class Deck(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Decks
        fields = (
            "deck_name",
            "deck_id",
            "deck_colors",
            "image_small",
            "deck_type",
            "user_id"
        )
```

Model

```
class Decks(models.Model):
    deck_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    deck_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="Standard")
    deck_colors = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="r")
    deck_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image_small = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='https://i.pinimg.com/564x/c3/f2/45/c3f245bdfa2ecc879530b205d8c1f972.jpg')
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: nvm, as soon as i psoted it realized the problem. Shoulda been user in serializer field and not user_id